# Connect Direct (NDM)

Tags: ibm-sterling

How to configure 2 nodes via connect direct in Unix environment?

I want to configure 2 nodes/system via connect direct to initiate the file transfer. I have heard that I need to make entries in netmap and userfile config files but not sure when and what entries to make in it. Please provide some basic ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to have a better clarification, you need two separate nodes to communicate using Connect Direct.

1. You need to have Connect Direct Client and server installed on both the systems.
2. In the netmap of node 1- add the IP and port of node 2 under remote node and similarly in the netmap of node 2, add the IP and port of node 1.

Secondly - in the userconfig file, add the user proxy- any user from remote node or specific user from remote node can submit jobs/process to the local node.

Note- by default IP is 1364, make sure firewall is open between the two nodes.

Try going through the installation guide it has this information detailed out